# Mongoose populate other syntaxes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models like this:

```
    var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name        : {type: String, required: true},
        image       : {type: String, required: true}
    });

    var RoomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _user   : {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
        name    : {type: String, required: true}
    });
```

I know how to use populate like this:

```
Room.findOne({_id : req.body._id}).populate('_user').exec(function(err, room){
     console.log(room);
});
```

And works fine, my problem is that I need to write something like (**witch is wrong**):

```
Room.findOne({_id : req.body._id}, function(err, room){
     room.populate('_user');
     console.log(room);
});
```

Because I have no access to the function that find the rooms and I have a long list of different Objects Ids that I need to populate. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Model.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) to do this:

```
Room.findOne({_id : req.body._id}, function(err, room){
     Room.populate(room, {path: '_user'}, function(err, room) {
         console.log(room);
     });
});
```

Comment: Can I send an array of documents (rooms instead of room) with the same syntax?

Comment: Yep, that's right in the documentation I linked to.